# Jetty is throwing `Unknown module' error when running with --add-to-start

Tags: jetty, jetty-9

I am trying to configure Jetty and facing this:

```
root@jans-dev:~/jetty-base# java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --add-to-start=http,deploy
ERROR : Unknown module='http'. List available with --list-modules

Usage: java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
       java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --help  # for more information
```

**Background**:

- Jetty 9.4 installed as `root` on an `lxc` container on Ubuntu using `sudo apt install jetty9`
- Jetty service is running and I can access default landing page
- Jetty home is set to `export JETTY_HOME=/usr/share/jetty`
- Jetty base is set to `export JETTY_BASE=/root/jetty-base`

I have executed below command successfully before trying to add modules.

```
root@jans-dev:~/jetty-base# java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --create-startd
MKDIR : ${jetty.base}/start.d
INFO  : Base directory was modified
```

Also, when I run `--list-modules`, it is coming up empty:

```
root@jans-dev:~/jetty-base# java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --list-modules

Available Modules:
==================
tags: [-internal]

Enabled Modules:
================
root@jans-dev:~/jetty-base#
```

I am not sure what am I missing here. How do I make modules available to Jetty? I have also checked this [reference](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#quickstart-common-config)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your linux distro has mangled the jetty distribution.

Does your `/usr/share/jetty` directory contain the directories `etc/`, `lib/`, and `modules/`?  If not, then that's not a valid `${jetty-home}`.

Perhaps your linux distribution put the jetty-home somewhere else?
But that would also be invalid, as the `start.jar` should be in the same directory as those other directories.

Example of what a proper `${jetty.home}` looks like ...

```sh
$ ls -la jetty-home-9.4.44.v20210927
total 776
drwxr-xr-x  6 joakim joakim   4096 Sep 27 18:12 ./
drwxr-xr-x 74 joakim joakim  12288 Nov  2 15:32 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 joakim joakim   4096 Oct  7 10:07 bin/
drwxr-xr-x  4 joakim joakim   4096 Oct 14 07:17 etc/
drwxr-xr-x 14 joakim joakim   4096 Oct  7 10:07 lib/
-rw-r--r--  1 joakim joakim  30012 Sep 27 18:12 license-eplv10-aslv20.html
drwxr-xr-x 22 joakim joakim   4096 Oct  7 10:07 modules/
-rw-r--r--  1 joakim joakim   6262 Sep 27 18:12 notice.html
-rw-r--r--  1 joakim joakim 163958 Sep 27 18:10 start.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 joakim joakim 550572 Sep 27 17:44 VERSION.txt
```

In the past, there were Linux Distributions that tried to put the various Jetty libs (The jar files in `${jetty.home}/lib/`) in their distribution setup as separate dependencies, but that's not a valid setup for a modular Servlet/Web Container like Jetty.  Most distributions have realized this and have reverted to a sane setup now.

The fastest fix for you is to remove this bad Jetty package from your linux distribution and just download and use the official tarball.

https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-home

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/download.php

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with ubuntu 22.04, but it does work if I first go to the JETTY_HOME folder before running the command:

```
pushd $JETTY_HOME
java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --list-modules
```